# pegar o status de pg_query e passar para variavel de php

Tags: php, postgresql

Imaginem a seguinte consulta:

```
pg_query($conn,"selects * from tabela");
```

Tendo em conta que tem um erro no `selects`,

> 'ERROR: syntax error at or near "selects" LINE 1: selects * from
>   tabela... ^'

Como poderei pegar esse resultado e passar para uma variavel php?

Testei das seguintes formas, mas sem sucesso:

## 1

```
$sql = 'selects * from table'
if(pg_query($conn,$sql)) $res = 'ok'; else $res = pg_last_error($conn);
```

## 2

```
$sql = pg_query($conn,"selects * from table");
if($sql) $res = 'ok'; else $res = pg_result_status($sql);
```

## 3

```
$sql = pg_query($conn,"selects * from table");
if(pg_affected_rows($sql)>0) $res = 'ok'; else $res = pg_result_status($sql);
```

## 4

```
$sql = pg_query($conn,"selects * from table");
if(pg_affected_rows($sql)>0) $res = 'ok'; else $res = pg_last_result($conn);
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que você quer, quer armazenar numa variável a mensagem do erro?

Comment: @AndréFilipe, isso mesmo.

Comment: Só uma curiosidade: Por que você está querendo forçar esse erro, por que não executar o comento corretamente?

Comment: @AndréFilipe, não estou a forçar, por vezes tem erro de escrita ao digitar o codigo e quero gravar essa informação, só isso

Comment: É SELECT e não SELECTS. Tira este s do final.

Comment: @anonimo, não leu a pergunta com atenção...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O comando [pg_last_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-last-error.php) obtém a última string de mensagem de erro de uma conexão, assim é necessário passar a string de conexão.

```
echo pg_last_error($conn);
```

Por exemplo o código abaixo:

```
<?php

// Variável de Conexão com o banco
$conn = pg_connect("host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=sistema user=luiz-justino password=#seTTT#323") or die("Não foi possível conectar ao servidor PostGreSQL");

// Query
$sql = "SELECTS * FROM tb_cliente c WHERE c.id = 7";
// Executa a query
$result = pg_query($conn, $sql);

// O comando abaixo exibirá o erro desta última query na conexão $conn
echo pg_last_error($conn);
```

A mensagem que irá aparecer foi de que a sintaxe do comando está errada (pois o certo é select ao invés de selects):
(como o meu php está configurado para exibir warnings está já aparecendo o erro, mas a captura deste erro se dá na linha marcada que é a que eu dei um echo utilizando a função `echo pg_last_error($conn);`)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pois quando se exeuta o [pg_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php) ele tem dois retornos possíveis:um recurso de resultado da consulta em caso de sucesso ou FALSE em caso de falha. Se um erro ocorrer e FALSE for retornado, detalhes do erro poderão ser recuperados usando a função pg_last_error () se a conexão for válida.